# Why do I get this error creating a web part page in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: web-part-page, powershell

The following appears to be the way to create a web part page in Sharepoint 2010 using Powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://somesite
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pageLayout = $pWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | Where { $_.Name -eq "BlankWebPartPage.aspx" }
$folder = $web.GetFolder("SitePages")
$page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage("spamDoc.aspx", $pageLayout, $folder)
```

But when I run it I get:

```
PS C:\Users\spadmin> $page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage("spamDoc.aspx", $pageLayout, $folder)
Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "3" argument(s): "Invalid field name. {fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}
At line:1 char:32
+ $page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage <<<< ("spamDoc.aspx", $pageLayout, $folder)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I am trying to create a new web part page in the site's **Site Pages** library.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: i think change the name of the page and also try to remove the folder parameter...

Comment: I have to have the folder parameter, I want the page built in the **SitePages** library.  If you do not use the folder parameter, the page is built in the **Pages** library by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's whining about the spamdoc.aspx, instead try without the .aspx. Try this instead.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://somesite
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pageLayout = $pWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | Where { $_.Name -eq "BlankWebPartPage.aspx" }
$folder = $web.GetFolder("SitePages")
$page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage("spamDoc", $pageLayout, $folder)
```

Comment: OK, I removed the .aspx from the page name and got:  
  
`PS C:\Users\spadmin> $page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage("spamDoc", $pageLayout, $folder)  
Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "3" argument(s): "The extension for the page URL name is not valid. Page URL names must have an .aspx exte
nsion.  
Parameter name: name"  
At line:1 char:32  
+ $page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage <<<< ("spamDoc", $pageLayout, $folder)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Comment: Nevermind, it's whining about the folder. Try without the folder. `$page = $pWeb.AddPublishingPage("spamDoc", $pageLayout)`

Comment: As I said above, if you don't specify the folder, it defaults to the **Pages** library.  That's not where I want the page built.

Comment: I know, I was saying to test it to see if the folder is the issue at hand. Then we can find out what's wrong with `$folder = $web.GetFolder("SitePages")`. Try `$web.Folders["SitePages"]` or the folder GUID `$web.GetFolder(GUID)`

Comment: Using `$web.Folders["SitePages"]` gave the same result.  If you mean to get the SPFolder object by using `$web.GetFolder[GUID]`, then it will give the same result.  The signature for the appropriate 3 parameter call to AddPublishingPage is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage AddPublishingPage(string name, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout layout, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder folder)`, which means it wants a SPFolder object, which is what I am giving it.  I checked the SPFolder object in the first 2 cases and it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://somesite
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pageLayout = $pWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | Where { $_.Name -eq "BlankWebPartPage.aspx" }
$page = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add("spamDoc.aspx", $pageLayout)
```

**UPDATE**

`Site Pages` library allows creation of `Wiki pages` and `Web Part Pages`. `BlankWebPartPage.aspx` has a `Page Layout` Content Type and this type of page can be created in a publishing library aka `Pages` library. `SPWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add` internally looks for this `Pages` library and adds the page to it. If you go into the `Pages` library and click on New Document and select Article Page you can find  `BlankWebPartPage.aspx` in the list of available page layouts. Now if you go ahead and add  `Article Page` content type to `Site Pages` library and then try to create a `BlankWebPartPage.aspx` or any other page from `Article Page` content type, you will get an error like this:

> Value does not fall within the expected range. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile(SPList
>   list, String url, Boolean createAsListItem) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.NewPageItemSave(String
>   pageName, PageLayout pageLayout, String folderUrl, Boolean redirect)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.CreateStandardPage(String
>   pageName) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.ButtonCreatePage_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   http://aissp2013/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx?List={353535BD-BF00-4280-B3C4-AB64F28A5720}&RootFolder=/sites/Team/SitePages&ContentTypeId=0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D002035528A8BBF824DA4DA7133B3E80214&Source=/sites/Team/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx
>   /_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx

`SPUtility.CreateParentFoldersForFile` verifies that the new item based on a publishing content type is stored in the `Pages` library. If not you get the error above.
This means that Publishing Content types work only in the Publishing Library, aka. `Pages` library.

Comment: How will this build the new page in the **SitePages** folder?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted to create page in site pages library.  This script will create page in pages library.

Comment: So no one knows how to do this?

Comment: @MichaelFrederick,see my updated answer.

Comment: That's interesting.  Maybe I am trying to use the wrong page template, because our site has many web part pages in the SitePages library, and they all work fine.  The UI allows you to create them there.  So I guess I either need to try a different template or a different creation method.

Comment: @MichaelFrederick, as mentioned in the answer, you can create web part pages but not a page of type `BlankWebPartPage`